# Grails dependency nightmare with Lucene

Tags: grails, lucene, dependencies

I have recently updated Elastic Search from 0.90.0 to 1.3.2 and now I'm getting a conflict with a Lucene version used by another dependency. The scenario look as follows:

jar A uses Lucene 4.9.0
jar B uses Lucene 3.3.0

The point is that I'm getting a java.lang.VerifyError because B code is overriding a final method of a Lucene's class which is not final at 4.9.0 version.

I've tried this with no success:

```
compile ('A')
compile ('B')
compile ('org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.9.0') {
    excludes(B)
}
compile ('org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:4.9.0') {
    excludes(B)
}
```

I don't know what more to do, any clues on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the latest version of Lucene, your exclusions are actually backwards.

Your declaration of B should look something like this:

```
compile ('B') {
    excludes "lucene-core", "lucene-analyzers-common"
}
```

Include any other lucene jars that might conflict in that list as well.

If you aren't specifically utilizing any lucene libraries (aside from the elasticsearch plugin) in your code, you can remove the explicit Lucene declarations.

I don't know enough about Lucene to tell you whether 4.9.0 is backwards compatible with 3.3.0, but this solution should at least make sure that 4.9.0 is what is on your project's classpath, and *not* 3.3.0

Comment: The problem is that B is redefining a method that is final in Lucene 3.3.0 but it's not final in 4.9.0, so I'm getting a java.lang.VerifyError because of this :(

Comment: That makes sense if 3.3.0 is still on the classpath. Can you confirm that it is no longer on the classpath? And which code is actually throwing the VerifyError?

Comment: The code thowring the VerifyError is a code located in B which is extending Lucene's Analyzer class and is redefining a method that is final in 3.3.0 and not final in 4.9.0

Comment: Right. So if 3.3.0 is not on the classpath anymore, this Verify error should go away.

Comment: Thanks guys, so I think I have a problem here... What about creating an uber jar containing B and its dependencies?

Comment: Per injecteer's comment, I don't think you are going to make this work with Lucene 4 and 3 in the same application. You may need to consider alternative options.